# Same or different instance when starting same activity from various places in app?

Tags: android

When I start a activity from startActivity method from various places in my app, does vm launches same (if already started previously from somewhere else) or different instance of the activity?

And what about the stack of activities maintained ?

I am starting my activity as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Dashboard.class);  
intent.putExtra("userid",getIntent().getStringExtra("userid"))  
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: that depends on your requirement, you can make it work the way you want using various types flags added to the intent that starts a particular activity . http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: Can you give us a hint why you want to know this? Remebering an activity instanstance can be problematic. For example if you change from protrait to landscape the activity is destroyed and a new instance is created (and thus looses all its local members)

Comment: @k3b i want to know how system works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depend on the launch mode you set on the activity. It can be standard, singleTop, singleTask or singleInstance. This link may help:

http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode

By default, the launch mode is Standard which means Android will create multiple instances of the activity.

Comment: does it mean the same for stacks of activity?

Comment: For standard' and 'singleTop', multiple activity instances can be instantiated and the instance will stay in the same task.
For 'singleTask' or 'singleInstance', the new instance will be the root activity of a new task (therefore new back stack).
Please see the offcial documentation to understand more about task and back stack: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html